# What does <String, String> mean?

Tags: java

So I'm sure this is a noob question, but while reading a post on Android programing I came across a line like so:

```
List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

My question is what does `<Map<String, String>>` mean?  I've tried Googling it but all I get are listings about operators in Java.

Comment: [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)

Comment: Remember that marking an answer as correct rewards both you and the answerer.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `List` and `Map` use generics. So your `List` is a list of `Map`s which are `Map`s with keys of type `String` and values of type `String`

[You can read here about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

a `Map<type, type>` is a collection that associates one of the first type with one of the second type. So a `Map<String, String>` associates a String with another String. This is an instance of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). The `List<Map<String, String>>` means you have a list that holds `Map`s that hold two `String`s

Answer (score 1):

This is a declaration using [Java Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).  You should parse the angle brackets not as mathematical operators, but as a sort of fancy parentheses surrounding types.  In functions, you pass instances of particular types as arguments; in generics, you pass the actual types as arguments.

Let's work from the inside out.  The first part to read is

```
Map<String, String>
```

This means "an instance of `Map` whose keys are `String`s and whose values are `String`s."  For example, this might associate peoples' names with their driver's license numbers.  We then use these as elements in a

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

which is a `List` of elements where each element is a `Map` from `String` keys to `String` values.  This might be, for example, a list of different name-to-driver's-license-IDs for different states.

You should probably read up on generics; they come up all the time in Java and are a pretty handy tool.  You will see them a lot as you continue your Java journey, and they're an invaluable tool to have in your programming arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `<Map<String, String>>` as a 'table'

```
|------------|------------|
|    "Key"   |    "Key"   |  <-- String
|------------|------------|
|   "Value"  |   "Value"  |  <-- String
|------------|------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) whose keys are Strings and whose values are Strings.